# how to access firebird from Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, firebird

dear all..
i have a DB which built use Mysql.

for this case, i want to access another server PC which have DB in firebird. i want to take some data inside that. Both of DB always connected, because i must get data every time. This is a scheduling data, so i must always connected to firebird from mysql.

But i have no experience to make connection between Mysql and firebird.
can you tell me how to do that?

what is the best way that must i choose, do some migration or convert or may make sync.?
any advance will be appreciate.thanks.

---

could I call the firebird 1st(use ibase_connect) then insert the data to mysql? i dont know how to insert data to Mysql DB after i get from firebird DB.

Comment: You want to take some data once in the life, periodically based in a schedule or in the event something occurs in the mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be use php can work.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>PHP + Firebird / Interbase test (connection)</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <H3>FB Connect test.</H3>
    <?php
    // DB definition of account
    define("DBNAME","xx.xxx.xx.xxx:D:\DATABASE\OCS DATA.FDB"); // data bsse name
    define("DBUSER","SYSDBA"); // user name
    define("DBPASS","masterkey"); // password

    // DB connection
    $dbh = ibase_connect(DBNAME,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    if ($dbh == FALSE) {
    echo 'could not connect to DB<BR>';
    } else {
    echo 'success to connect to DB<BR>';
    // DB dis connection
    ibase_close($dbh);
    }
    ?>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: You can write a schedule (cron) task that will pump data from Firebird to Mysql using a for each loop row (fir each row from firebird table insert into mysql table ) http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2010/10/howto-and-tips-converting-from-mysql-to.html

Answer (score 0):

At this MySQL server can only connect to other MySQL servers. Not sure about Firebird, but if it's similar, then you need to do all you data handling in external application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQL Migration Toolkit. According to this [post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?104,115703,115703) firebird is supported.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest migrating firebird data to MySQL, this would help you avoid some pain in the ass :)

Unfortunately I have a project which has to be synced with some external firebird db...